# how to successfully run a c++ file which uses ogdf libraries

Tags: c++, ogdf

I compiled the file (source.cpp) using the command

g++ -I/home/hrishikesh/Desktop/OGDF-snapshot/include -O2 source.cpp -o mytest -L/home/hrishikesh/Desktop/OGDF-snapshot/_release -lOGDF -lCOIN -pthread

and it got compiled successfully without giving any error message,resulting a file "mytest" in the same folder as the source.cpp in.
when I try to run the mytest file using command

./mytest

it shows this error message

./mytest: error while loading shared libraries: libOGDF.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to put libOGDF.so in the same folder than mytest

Answer (score 0):

> g++ -I /**AbsolutePath**/Desktop/OGDF/ main.cpp  -L -l 
>   /**AbsolutePath**/Desktop/OGDF/_release/libOGDF.a  -lpthread

here main.cpp is the file.
copy and paste the line above in other text editors to get rid of the confusions between the usage of **I and L** and the spaces.

Be sure that you are writing the **absolute path correct**.
The **a.out file** will be generated in current directory. execute it by using:
**./a.out**